# How do i change VSC's terminal to system default

Tags: windows-10, terminal, visual-studio-code

I have come across an issue where VSC's in-built terminal uses a Linux based terminal rather than the system default terminal system.

How can I change the terminal environment back to the windows default?

I did at one point install the terminal environment when i was using the `Hyper.js` terminal however since then VSC's terminal has not been using the system default.

[[image: VSC screen shot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out a solution to my problem, which is as follows:

1. go to file > preferences > settings
2. select workspace > features > terminal and scroll until you see this: [settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/soJkl.png)
3. look for "integrated > Env:Windows" and click "Edit in settings.json" [It should look something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SsjjH.png)
4. locate "terminal.integrated.shell.windows": under user settings
5. make sure the directory to point to "C:\WINDOWS\System32\cmd.exe"
6. load terminal and check if works. if it doesnt then idk, this method worked for me.

I hope that this might help others in the future.